# Complex Average Function

Tags: excel

I am in over my head with this function which almost seems impossible to me. Here is what I am trying to do

**Edit:**

Here is the full data set that I should have included from the start

```
    5:00 AM 6:00 AM 7:00 AM 8:00 AM 9:00 AM 10:00 AM    11:00 AM    12:00 PM    1:00 PM 2:00 PM 3:00 PM 4:00 PM 5:00 PM 6:00 PM 7:00 PM









































5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      3               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     5               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     4               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     5               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     4               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 16:00 5/23/2016 17:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 17:00 5/23/2016 18:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 18:00 5/23/2016 19:00                                     1               











































5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 6:00  5/23/2016 7:00                                      3               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 7:00  5/23/2016 8:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      2               
5/23/2016 8:00  5/23/2016 9:00                                      1               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     5               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 9:00  5/23/2016 10:00                                     4               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     5               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 10:00 5/23/2016 11:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     4               
5/23/2016 11:00 5/23/2016 12:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 12:00 5/23/2016 13:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 13:00 5/23/2016 14:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 14:00 5/23/2016 15:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     3               
5/23/2016 15:00 5/23/2016 16:00                                     2               
5/23/2016 16:00 5/23/2016 17:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 17:00 5/23/2016 18:00                                     1               
5/23/2016 18:00 5/23/2016 19:00                                     1
```

The expected output would be

```
5:00 AM 6:00 AM 7:00 AM 8:00 AM 9:00 AM 10:00 AM    11:00 AM    12:00 PM    1:00 PM 2:00 PM 3:00 PM 4:00 PM 5:00 PM 6:00 PM 7:00 PM
0.00    5.00    3.00    8.00    14.00   8.00    10.00   9.00    7.00    6.00    6.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    0.00
```

Comment: I am having a hard time following, how do the numbers across the top relate to the table below?

Comment: so in the full data set I would have average spread out across from 5 to 12 and the corresponding data below would lend itself to that. My example is for just one time slot

Comment: Nevermind I think I get it

Comment: You want to get the value by hour then divide by the number of days?

Comment: The idea is that I want the average values per day. That they are coming from different locations doesnt matter, only when they came in. As such the data is technically 6 and 18 for the 2 days.

To your above, correct!

Comment: @Josh I think changing your sample data to have different hours should make it much clearer for everyone

Comment: Did you try mine then?  I believe it does what you want.

Comment: @Scott I think yours will do what I am looking for but I was having a hard time getting it in place. I will be working on it more as soon as I get home. (about to be driving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(TIME(HOUR($A$7:$A$12),MINUTE($A$7:$A$12),SECOND($A$7:$A$12))=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)),$C$7:$C$12))/SUM(IF(TIME(HOUR($A$7:$A$12),MINUTE($A$7:$A$12),SECOND($A$7:$A$12))=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)),1/COUNTIFS($A$7:$A$12,$A$7:$A$12)))
```

It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Using your expanded data, I needed to deal with the 0 count:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(IF(TIME(HOUR($A$7:$A$48),MINUTE($A$7:$A$48),SECOND($A$7:$A$48))=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)),$C$7:$C$48))/SUM(IF(TIME(HOUR($A$7:$A$48),MINUTE($A$7:$A$48),SECOND($A$7:$A$48))=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1)),1/COUNTIFS($A$7:$A$48,$A$7:$A$48))),0)
```

It still needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: @Josh look into this but wait a while for others to answer, they may find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sum up column C (24)
2. Count of the number of distinct days (2)
3. Divide the first by the second.

It'll be cleaner you make separate column for the date only (no time). Here's the formulas:

In column D:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(A7)
```

Drag it down. And in any empty cell:

```
=SUM(C7:C12)/SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(D7:D12,D7:D12)>0,1,0))
```

Comment: This would work for this small amount, but the OP wants it by the hour.  The data may show only one hour at the moment, but the real data has more than one hour.  That way the op can drag the formula across each hour on top to get the average sum per hour per day. At least that is the way I see it.  I may be wrong.

Comment: Column D strips away the hour. I think the OP said "average by day"

Comment: I am going by his last question. so again I may be wrong.  we will see.  If you are correct and the hour does not matter this is a very concise way to do it.  Is the last formula an Array formula?

Comment: No, just a regular formula

Comment: Hopefully not tripping on my words. The intent is to get the average value per day. The different values for the same times from different locations must be added together before dividing by the number of days.

Comment: @Josh so you want it broken out by hour or just day?

Comment: By hour averages combining the values of that hour from each location. I think it would be more help to see my full data set but I was not sure how best to make it available without flooding the screen.

Comment: @Josh you are describing your approach to the problem. Give the raw data and expected output